# credential should be scoped to correct service error - AWS IOT

Tags: amazon-web-services, postman, aws-iot

I have an IOT thing on my AWS account. Using python code I can easily get status and update device shadow via REST api but when I try to use postman to get or update device shadow it gives me an error saying "credential should be scoped to correct service".
I am 100% sure that credentials and permissions are correct because using python code I can make successful requests. I used this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-use-postman-to-call-api.html but its not giving me device updates.
Here is the screenshot for request.

[image]

Error message
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when the Service Name was set to 'execute-api' (as indicated by the documentation you point to) instead of 'lambda'.